# Hive support for filtering Unicode data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table with Unicode data. When trying to perform a simple query "SELECT * FROM table," I get back the correct data in correct Unicode encoding. However, when I tried to add filtering criteria such as "... WHERE column = 'some unicode value'," my query returned nothing.

Is it Hive's limitation? Or is there anyway to make Unicode filtering work with Hive?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide some example data? Maybe you should try using `LIKE` instead of `=`

Comment: Hi visakh, I used LIKE and it didn't work, either. Here is a sample query: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%你好%'" One possible reason is the Unicode characters got converted to ?? when being sent to Hive.

Answer (score 0):

you should use utf-8 format and load data into hive table, then you can get the data use what you've wrote before, e.g. ... name like '%你好%'